# How to decline citation using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, citing, natbib

In Finnish language we need to decline words. So how to do this when I do textual citation? I would like to use some custom command like `\customcitet[Greenwaden]{greenwade93}`. I would appreciate solution without conflicts with biblatex (with natbib commands) package.

Here is minimal example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{bibfile.bib}
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = "George D. Greenwade",
    title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
    year    = "1993",
    journal = "TUGBoat",
    volume  = "14",
    number  = "3",
    pages   = "342--351"
}
\end{filecontents}
\usepackage[%
natbib,%
authordate,%
backend=biber,%
noibid,
language=finnish,%
]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{bibfile}
\begin{document}
Now I get this: \citet{greenwade93}.

But I want something like this: Greenwaden (1993).
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: I cannot see any difference in your example...

Comment: @Yorgos - "Greenwade" vs "Greenwade**n**"

Comment: @Lesenger -- we could probably close this question unless you are still hoping for a inflection-sensitive custom `\cite` key. What do you think?

Comment: Until and unless natural language analysis becomes *way more sophisticated*, no software system can reliably pick up which declension form should be used. The situation is comparable to that in the `cleveref` package, which generates "clever" cross-references: The label prefixes   generated by `\cref` ("section", "figure", theorem", etc) are all in nominative form, for every language localization. If you happen to write in a language that declines nouns, you simply mustn't use `\cref` if the noun isn't in the nominative form. Instead, write out the correct form of the noun plus `\labelcref`.

Comment: @jon yes we could. This question didn't end up being so helpful, but if someone knows an article about language localization in tex, maybe it could be linked to this question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Edit**

From the comments, it turns out that all that a satisfactory answer is to type out the name of the author in the appropriately inflected form and then use `\parencite*{<entrykey>}`.

**Original suggestion**

Here's one way to do it.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents*}{bibfile.bib}
@preamble{ "\newif\ifdecline" }
@preamble{ "\newcommand\finale{\ifdecline en\else e\fi}" }
@article{greenwade93,
    author  = {George D. Greenwad\finale },
    title   = {The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})},
    year    = {1993},
    journal = {TUGBoat},
    volume  = {14},
    number  = {3},
    pages   = {342--351}
}
\end{filecontents*}
\usepackage[%
natbib,%
authordate,%
backend=biber,%
noibid,
language=finnish,%
]{biblatex-chicago}
\bibliography{bibfile}

\newcommand\dcitet[1]{\AtNextCite{\declinetrue}\citet{#1}}

\begin{document}
Now I get this: \dcitet{greenwade93}.

But I want something like this: Greenwaden (1993).

\citet{greenwade93}

\end{document}
```

[image: decline.png]

Comment: This would be nice if my problem would be as simple as my example. Actually I have quite many references in my bib file and declension depends on context so I may have to refer to Greenwade as Greenwaden, Greenwadenilla, Greenwadenin or ...

Comment: Command where I could manually write whole authors name like `\customcitet[Greenwaden]{greenwade93}` would be best I think. If that is not possible, I could write manually whole citation `Greenwadenilla (1993)` but I'd like bibliography/reference list to autamatically update.

Comment: Most simple solution I come up with is just use `Greenwadenilla (\citeyear{greenwade93})`. Hyperref doesn't seem to work, but `citeyear` command at least adds item to bibliography.

Comment: Well, I can't actually answer your question if you don't provide the required details. (You didn't even mention `hyperref`..!) I have to point out that typing `\customcitet[Greenwaden]{greenwade93}` is not more efficient, and far more error prone, than a simple `Greenwaden \parencite*{greenwade93}` (which will also work with `hyperref` by default). So I'm not sure your proposed solution to a still unclearly-defined question is worth pursuing.

Comment: That parencite* command will do. Thanks. That hyperref feature wasn't necessary. And I don't see why original question was unclear. I asked for custom command for citing where I could manually write authors declined name.

Comment: Sure, but you suggested only two declensions were needed; later, many more were needed (and I don't know Finnish). If there are only two, a simple conditional will work; if several were needed, I would've suggested something different. Your question also implied that a *non-manual* solution was wanted because it was always an option to simply write a name outside of the `\cite` command. I appreciate -- very much! -- the fact that you made a minimal example; but aspects of it were perhaps too minimal some some people, like me.